How can I visualize WDL workflows?
I would like to graphically visualize my workflow. I tried with Pipeline Builder but I didn't succeed as the http://pb.opensource.epam.com webpage doesn't work.
Thanks!

Putting your question title into a search engine returned https://github.com/miniwdl-ext/wdlviz, is that what you need? If not, please [edit] your question and describe your requirements. What do you want to give as input? What kind of output are you expecting? Can you give us a simple example to play with?
